# How to display the button based on the alphabet in front of the file name?

Tags: php

I am created the button to display buttons based on the alphabet in front of the file. Anyone can guide me how to display buttons based on the first alphabet in front of the file. For my files, my files name first alphabet is m. I want just show the `Edit Meeting File` button if file name first alphablet is m, if alphabet not is m , just don't show the `Edit Meeting File` button. Below is my code:

```html
<?php
$i = 1;
$files = scandir("upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file");
$date = $files[$a];
for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++) {

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td> <a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" target="_blank"> <?php echo $files[$a]; ?></a></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a href="upload_dms_file/uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>"
                                                      download="<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Download</a></button>
            &nbsp &nbsp
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                        href="upload_dms_file/delete_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Delete
                </a></button>

                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                        href="upload_dms_file/edit_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                    Edit Meeting File 
                </a></button>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
} ?>
```

This is my output page, this output is show all the  `Edit Meeting File` button:
[image: Output1]

Hope anyone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the code that outputs that button in an `if` block that checks whether the first letter of the filename is `m`:

```
<?php
if ($files[$a][0] == 'm') {
?>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
        href="upload_dms_file/delete_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
    Edit Meeting File 
</a></button>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `if` clause to the button part:

```
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                    href="upload_dms_file/delete_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                Edit Meeting File 
            </a></button>
```

should be

```
            <?php if(strlen($files[$a]) > 1 and substr($files[$a], 0, 2) = "m-"){ ?>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><a
                    href="upload_dms_file/delete_filing_storage.php?name=uploads_filing_file/<?php echo $files[$a]; ?>" style="color: white;">
                Edit Meeting File 
            </a></button>
            <?php } ?>
```